# Operador ternário Vue.js dentro de Tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou criando um component em Vuejs que quero enviar uma propriedade ao component para exibir ou ocultar um atributo dentro da tag utilizando operador ternário.

As Aspas duas não funcionam dentro da tag.

O resultado seriam essas duas possibilidades:

se multiple for true

```
<div>
    <select name="select" multiple>
    </select>
</div>
```

se o multiple for false

```
<div>
    <select name="select">
    </select>
</div>
```

Estado do componente atual

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select name="select" {{multiple ? 'multiple' : ''}}">
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
props: {
        multiple: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Exemplo de chamada para o component

```
<component-select :multiple="false"></component-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução para o problema pode ser:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select v-if="multiple" name="select" multiple>
        <select v-else="multiple" name="select">
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: não foi exatamente como você apresentou, mas deu pra pegar a ideia.

Answer (score 2):

Você também poderia fazer

```
 <select name="select" :multiple = "multiple"/>
```

depende muito do que você pretende, mas acredito que na maioria dos casos essa forma seria mais eficiente pois na hora de dar manutenção não iria ter retrabalho pra fazer os dois selects funcionarem

Answer (score 1):

Modifiquei a resposta acima só pra dar uma complementada. Mas eu segui a ideia do @pedroolavo

```
<div>
    <select name="select" v-if="multiple" multiple>
    </select>

    <select name="select" v-else>
    </select>
</div>
```